# масштабирование проекта на разные регионы, как это технически реализовывается

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vds

допустим у меня есть один проект клиентская на nuxt + бекенд сервер на node.
все прекрасно работает в одном регионе, но на другом уже начинаются тормоза плюс уже бекенд не справляется с запросами в большом количестве. база данных то же лежит в одном месте на vds с клиентской и бекендом.

как технически подключить отдельный сервер и сихрнизировать все запросы с сервером и базами данных ? есть какие то готовые решения для этого?

p.s. вопрос дилетантский

Comment: Добро пожаловат в мир боли) Смотрите в сторону балансировщиков нагрузки и репликации баз данных (master-slave). Но это точно не тот вопрос, на который можно так просто дать ответ, не в рамках вопроса SO

Comment: сколько запросов в секунду (в минуту/в час) у вас к бекенду? сколько памяти на вашем сервере?

Comment: вопрос скорее из интереса и возможно на будущее, пока все работает, хотя для некоторых регионов загрузка выполняется долго, поэтому интересно как это решается